# Ruby on Rails: NameError in StatusesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi iam getting this error:NameError in StatusesController#create
uninitialized constant Status::Name

I am not sure where the error is but it says:app/controllers/statuses_controller.rb:27:in `create'

this is my Project on github https://github.com/Jigmet/Treebook

Answer (score 2):

you have

```
params.require(:status).permit(:name, :content)
```

But you have no column `name` in your db/schema.rb so you don't have that field in your model.

You either need to add the column through a migration, or remove it from your params.

The error message means look at line 27 of your statuses controller, by the way.

Comment: I am new to Ruby On Rails, yet to get a gang of it. Can you please guide me with the necessary steps?? to solve the problem.

Comment: The expression is "the hang of it". I would like to help but this is the wrong forum and someone would need to understand what your requirements and objectives are. Do you have a local community of ror developers? Is try there first.

Answer (score 0):

You removed the column "name" in your migration file called `20150121142351_add_user_id_to_statuses.rb`

In that file you removed the column like this:

```
 remove_column :statuses, :name
```

Create the field again and your problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to get rid of the :name column? If you did, then just change this:

```
params.require(:status).permit(:name, :content)
```

to this:

```
params.require(:status).permit(:content)
```

If you still need that :name column, then

rails generate migration AddNameToStatuses
and in the migration file, write the following:

```
def change
    add_column :statuses, :name, :string
end
```

After you do that, then run: rake db:migrate, restart your server and you should be good to go!

Comment: Awesome. Please select as Answered :)